# Entity Framework Core instance cannot be tracked because another instance

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have this microservice API for a web application with .net core 2.1, and I always have this problem.
In my service layer, I try to read an object from the repository. If such record does not exist in the database, I create one from scratch and insert it.

```
ConfigKeyDto configKey = await _configKeyRepository.GetByKey("LAST_DEMO_ACCOUNT_ID");

if (configKey == null)
{
    configKey = GetConfigKey();
    await _configKeyRepository.InsertConfigKey(configKey);
}
```

The I do some processing, update the dto's values and later on I try to update it, like this

```
await _configKeyRepository.UpdateConfigKey(configKey);
```

I end up getting the infamous "The instance of entity type 'ConfigKey' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for 'Id' is already being tracked".
Below are my repository code:

```
public async Task<bool> InsertConfigKey(ConfigKeyDto configKey)
{
    ConfigKey configKeyEnt = _mapper.Map<ConfigKey>(configKey);
    configKeyEnt.Active = true;
    configKeyEnt.CreateAt = System.DateTime.Now;

    _context.Add<ConfigKey>(configKeyEnt);

    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();            

    return true;
}

public async Task<bool> UpdateConfigKey(ConfigKeyDto configKey)
{
    ConfigKey configKeyEnt = await _context.ConfigKeys.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Key == configKey.Key);

    _context.Entry(configKeyEnt).State = EntityState.Modified;
    _context.Entry(configKeyEnt).CurrentValues.SetValues(configKey);

    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return true;
}
```

I've stumbled upon this many times, whenever I have to read/insert an entity in a method, and later on update it. What's the correct way to do this without resorting to a kludge (like disposing the context, or working directly with the database entity outside my repository layer which I don't like so I use automapper)?

Thanks in advance

UPDATE

I put this in all my repository methods

```
_context.Entry<ConfigKey>(obj).State = EntityState.Detached;
```

It worked

Comment: Disposing the context is all but a kludge. You saying this suggests you have long-lived context instances, which is against all recommendations.

Comment: We use a scoped db context, which lives as long the API endpoint call from the frontend does. I have always worked like that, but everytime it involves a select/insert followed by an update, I get this.

Answer (score 0):

Detaching the entity objects worked.

_context.Entry(obj).State = EntityState.Detached;